# node JS client vs server

Tags: node.js, express, server, client

I am a PHP developer and have recently made some use of node JS with express.

One thing i am confused about is how you tell your express server if a javascript file should be executed on the server or sent to the browser to be executed on the client side.

In PHP this is not a problem because each filetype (php, pearl, jpg, js) has a dedicated location (server or client) where it runs. The same is true of HTTP apps programmed other languages such as Java and C#

consider this sample code

> var express = require('express'); var app = express();
>
> app.get('/some_page', function(req, res)
>   {    res.send('hello world');  });
>
> app.listen(3000);

There is no JS involved so 'hello world' is sent to the browser and is rendered by the browser.

But what if the code was

> var express = require('express'); var app = express();
>
> app.get('/', function(req, res){   res.send('console.log('hello
>   world')'); });
>
> app.listen(3000);

This time we have the JS function console.log()
So how does node.js know if if should run this code or send it to the browser.

Comment: It seems you need to learn basics of node.js prior jumping to express.js

Answer (score 4):

this is all whithin the `app.get('/', function(req, res){` and `}` tags

```
res.send('console.log("hello world!")')
```

will print `console.log("hello world!")` on the clients page

```
res.send('<html><body><script>console.log("hello world!");</script></body></html>')
```

will print `hello world!` in the console of the client

```
 res.send('hello world!');
 console.log("hello world!");
```

will print `hello world!` on the page of the client and on the servers console.

so basicly all you send to the client will be done client-side and code that you dont send to the client will be done server-side

**EDIT**

like [Ankur Rana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479405/ankur-rana) said you can also send Html files

```
res.sendFile('index.html');
```

and in the same directory as this file we have a file named index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="myId">console.log("hello world!")</div>
    <script>
        //regular js here
     $("#myId").html("Hello World!");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `express`, so you should explicitly specify client side Javascript code using `static` middleware.

In the example below you define `public` directory to store it.

```
// GET /style.css etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Everything else will be executed on the server side.

More about middleware: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the javascript code in script tag of a HTML file and send it using 
res.sendFile('pathToFile.html')